# T-SQL Date function with Integer values as date parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datediff

I was trying to modify a legacy query and come across this code block

```
select   DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1,getdate() )-1, 1)
```

But in my belief the dateadd and datediff function needs some date parameter to do the calculation. But here the DateDiff and DateAdd has some integer values at the place of Date parameter

For example  DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1,getdate() )-1 returns 1431 which is just a decimal value, but the code block according documentation looks for Date parameter.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp

Same in the case of DateAdd as well

Someone please share some explanation

Comment: Note that W3School pages are often [inaccurate](https://www.w3fools.com/). Always refer to [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I'd never recommend that site.

Comment: `w3school` is `w3school` - a site with *entry level HTML and Javascript* tutorials with some SQL databases thrown in. It's not SQL Server's documentation. It's not Mozilla's MDN either - don't expect it to have better docs on the Fetch or File API than MDN. It may be a nice way to find out about the *existence* of a function, but the actual docs are far better and quite often easier to use. Even google returns the *doc sites* before `W3School`

Comment: This manual page on W3School is wrong : *"Return the difference between two date values, in years:"* This is wrong. This returns an int that is the difference between 2 dates, but in the format defined by the first argument. `DATEDIFF(MONTH, ...)` returns the number of monthes, not years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF` are specified to work with `datetime` (as well as any of the newer datetime datatypes). As such, they inherit a lot of the nastiness of the old type, including that [*implicit* conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) from `int` to `datetime` are allowed<sup>1</sup>.

`0` converts to `1900-01-01`. `-1` converts to `1899-12-31`. `1` converts to `1900-01-02`. In short, the integer is converted to the day "that many" days after 1900-01-01.

But lets look at your code. It calculates the difference in *months* from `1899-12-31` and then, having subtracted one, adds that same number of months onto `1900-01-02`. The net effect of this is to give you the 2nd of whatever the current month is.

There are simpler ways to write this even keeping the same structure:

```
select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, getdate() ), 1)
```

Or using [`DATEFROMPARTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), which is preferred because it makes it explicit/obvious what you're doing *and* uses a more modern datatype (`date`).

---

<sup>1</sup>You're not even allowed *explicit* conversions from `int` to `datetime2`. Because, really, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. well explained